# how to replace keys from a file with values python

Tags: python, traceroute

I'm learning Python, my task is to replace the IP addresses from traceroute with the hostnames, eg:

```
from :      
  1     8 ms     6 ms     6 ms  203.109.92.1
To:
  1     6 ms    11 ms     7 ms  hyd-core01.youbroadband.in
```

I wrote the following program, my logic was to save the traceroute in a file, open and find the IP address (I used regex) then in another for loop do the lookup and save the output as a dictionary as {ip:hostname}.

It is successful until here.Now I need to open the file again, find the  IP address (which is the key) and replace it with the value in the dictionary.

```
import re                                                                                          
import socket                                                                                      

open_host = open('C:/Users/Desktop/traceroute.txt','r' )                                           

#print  traceroute                                                                                 

ip = []                                                                                            
iptoname={}                                                                                        

for line in open_host:                                                                             
   ipPattern = re.search(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})',line)       
   #print ipPattern.group()                                                                        
   ip.append(ipPattern.group())                                                                    
#print ip                                                                                          

for i in ip:                                                                                       
    try:                                                                                           
         #print i                                                                                  
         #print type(socket.gethostbyaddr(i))                                                      
         name = socket.gethostbyaddr(i)[0]                                                         
         #print name                                                                               

         iptoname[i] = name                                                                        
         #print iptoname                                                                           
    except Exception as e:                                                                         
         print e.message                                                                           

#print "this is dictionary", iptoname                                                              
with open('C:/Users/Desktop/traceroute.txt', 'w') as f:                                     
    f.writelines([v[0] for v in iptoname().itervalues()])
```

Comment: You can read the file again, use the same regex and substitute the matches with the corresponding values from your dict. `re.sub` can do that. It's easier to write the results to a new file, though.

Comment: Show at least**one** Record from your _traceroute.txt_. [Edit] your Question accordingly.